# Passing textbox value to Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

After page loaded, user will give a value to textbox. I want to give that value as parameter to my Action. I am new to MVC and don't know how to do. I know that Html.Textbox name should be same as parameter but i'm conflicted about when i call that action, parameter will be empty so i will take parameter missing error.

This is my html:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EventID, new { id = "eventID" })
```

This is my action:

```
public ActionResult DownloadAttendeeExcel(int eventID)
        {
           return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for helpers tie the value of the field to your model.  so if on your view you have

```
@model ViewModel
```

at the top and EventID is part of that model then change your controller to

```
public ActionResult DownloadAttendeeExcel(ViewModel model)...
```

and that will have that value of that text box.  Being an id you probably don't want the user to change it so in that case I would put that value in a hidden for

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.EventID)
```

so the value passed to the view will be passed back to the controller